# Projectile maximum height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

How can I determine the needed initial velocity to make a 2d wind resistance free projectile (in computer simulation) reach maximum height at a certain x distance away, with launch position and target position on uneven ground?

Comment: You can use the fact that when it reaches max height, it will be travelling horizontally, i.e. it will stop moving further up.

Comment: You will have to calculate multiple trajectories based on varying initial conditions, and adjust according to the results.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you have a projectile, and, given target x and y coordinates and an x coordinate of your trajectory's peak, you want to vary the angle and speed of your launch to hit both locations. Is that correct?

I did the math out myself, so someone may want to double check (and I may have picked a very inefficient/inconvenient way to do this, so don't take my word as the holy gospel of physics problems), but my method was this:

If we say the projectile starts out above the target coordinates, and we know that it will take an equal amount of time to reach the trajectory's peak as it will to fall back to our starting level, then the total time in the air will be twice the time to reach the peak, plus an additional period of time to fall past the starting height to the target point. Call this (2t_max + t_height).

Since you can break a projectile's motion into components, you can also analyze your target's horizontal motion at a constant velocity. Given your target x coordinate, and a constant horizontal velocity, you can solve for the time it takes to travel that distance at that speed. Call that (t_x).

Now, obviously, the amount of time it takes to rise and fall to the target point is the same as the time it takes to travel horizontally to the target point. Mathematically, (2t_max + t_height = t_x). I went about this by solving for each of those three terms separately, and plugging in the results to get an equation in terms of initial velocity, angle of launch, and the x and y target coordinates. Next, you note that, since the horizontal component of velocity is constant, the x distance to the maximum is easy to solve for in terms of that component of velocity and the t_max term you solved for previously. Doing that gives you a system of equations with the max x coordinate and target x and y coordinates as knowns, and the initial launch speed and angle as unknowns.

If you've gotten there, solving the rest should just be algebra. I plugged into Wolfram Alpha because I didn't feel like solving and got a pretty unpleasant looking result, so it's possible there's a more elegant way to solve this that gives a more reasonable answer, or that my method doesn't actually work at all, but I hope this helps a bit.